# Is every sentential form also a right-sentential form?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, parsing

Ullman's Introduction to Automata, Languages and Computing (1979) says

> 10.6 LR(0) GRAMMARS
>
> ...
>
> A right-sentential form is a sentential form that can be derived by a rightmost derivation.

Is every sentential form also a right-sentential form, by definition? (I guess so.) In Chapter 4 Context Free Grammars, I learned that

- Given a CFG, a sentential form is a string of terminals and nonterminals which can be derivable from the start symbol.

  Since a sentential form is derivable from the start symbol, there exists at least one parse tree from the start symbol and the sentential form.
- > If w is in L(G) for CFG G, then w has at least one parse tree, and corresponding to a particular parse tree, w has a unique leftmost and a unique rightmost derivation.

  I think the same can be generalized from a string of terminals to a sentential form.

So isn't it that each sentential form always has at least one rightmost derivation? Therefore, isn't every sentential form also a right-sentential form, by definition?
Why is the concept of "right sentential form" introduced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}S&\to A B\\
A&\to a\\
B&\to b\\
\end{align}
$$
For this grammar, $aB$ is not a right sentential form because $A$ was not the rightmost non-terminal when it was replaced. So $aB$ cannot appear in any rightmost derivation even though it can be derived.

Comment: Is a  string of terminals, if it is derivable from the start symbol, always a right sentential form ?

Comment: @tim: yes. If there is a derivation of a terminal string, then there is a right derivation. So the sentence must be a right sentential form.